# Error GRPC Spanner Google Cloud With PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm using PHP to try using the **Google Cloud Spanner**. I already did the **gCloud** settings and everything, and that's right. Now I need to make the connection via **PHP** to do a CRUD with the database that is in Spanner, but the code below always returns the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Undefined constant 'Grpc\STATUS_UNKNOWN' in
>   /xxx/xxxx/www/vendor/google/cloud-spanner/Connection/Grpc.php on line
>   129

The code I have is:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Spanner\SpannerClient;

/* Error start here */
$spanner = new SpannerClient([
    'projectId' => 'my-project-id'
]);

$db = $spanner->connect('instance', 'database');

$userQuery = $db->execute('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = @login', [
    'parameters' => [
        'login' => 'devteam'
    ]
]);

$user = $userQuery->rows()->current();

echo 'Hello ' . $user['login'];
```

The requirements I use in the composer are:

```
"require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.32.1",
        "google/cloud-spanner": "^0.2.2"
}
```

*I noticed that if I enter through the browser, the error presented above continues to appear. If I run the command **php teste.php** on the terminal, it runs the script correctly, ie, the terminal works and the browser does not.*

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud PHP's spanner client is gRPC only. This means to use it you will need to install the gRPC PHP extension:

```
pecl install grpc
```

Once you have done that, add `google/proto-client-php` and `google/gax` to your composer.json and run `composer update`. After this is done, the error will be resolved.

Comment: I installed the cloud-spanner that comes with some dependencies that you quoted in the versions that it needs, but nothing happens. I also installed the GRPC and it's no good. I tested here and if I enter through the browser, it returns the error that I reported in the post, but if I type in the terminal **php teste.php** it runs the script normally.

Comment: Sounds as though your installation of PHP uses different configuration files for the web server and for the cli. Make sure you add the 'extension=grpc.so' to the php.ini file for the web server as well.

Comment: Running `phpinfo()` in the browser, you should find the path to `php.ini` near the top, labeled as "Configuration File (php.ini) Path". Running `php -i | grep "Configuration File (php.ini)"` in the terminal should show a different path or filename.

Answer (score 1):

For those wanting more detailed instructions, see [this page](http://cloud.google.com/php/grpc) for installing and enabling gRPC for PHP!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that it works on CLI but not on browser, I can say that you need to enable the grpc extension on your php web server config.

E.g. Add 
`extension=grpc.so` to your /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini